# Rails Devise polymorphic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, polymorphic-associations

I am using devise and I want create a polymorphic relationship, I added the columns to table users 'usersable_type' and 'usersable_id'

This is my code

**Model >> User**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  #usarsable
  belongs_to :usersable, :polymorphic => true, :autosave => true, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :usersable

end
```

**Model >> Medic**

```
class Medic < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :license_number, :specialty

  has_one :user, as: :usersable, dependent: :destroy
  has_and_belongs_to_many :patients
end
```

**Model >> Patient**

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :socialsecurity
  attr_accessible :birthday, :blood_type
  has_one :user, as: :usersable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :contacts
  has_and_belongs_to_many :medics
end
```

**Override Devise Controller**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super
    @user.build_usersable # I had problem in this line
  end

  def create
  end

  def update
    super
  end
end
```

**Those are all the models I have for the moment, but I still have the same problem, I dont know how create and save the polymorphic object.**

The error still is the same

> ERROR: undefined method `build_usersable' for "<#User:"

Is anyone can help me I would be grateful

Regards and thanks in advance

Juli.

Comment: I dont quite understand what you need.  Do you want a medic to belong to a user?  What does a user belong to?  I think what you are after is that you have more than one model that will belong_to user, if that is the case you dont need polymorphic.

Comment: Yes, of course, I have other models like patient and admin, I put only medic for example. Sorry for the delay and very thanks!!

Comment: I still dont get why you need a polymorphc relationship, why dont you simply have the user_id in Medic and use belongs_to user?  Will a single user have many userable associations? if so then you will need a join table.  Please provide more details with an example of another model like medic and I will be happy to come up with an example implementation.

Comment: Because I want all users in a table using devise, I want to know what type of user is as soon as possible, because the system connects to an user, not a doctor nor patient, and with the user you can get the doctor or patient. The differences in the models, the doctor will have several patients and on the other hand the patients will have several emergency contacts, blood type, shift, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the conversation in the comments this is the kind of scheme i think you need.

I am going to use the concept of Aspect, that is a user can have many aspects, the aspect might be a medic, a content detail etc; an Aspect can have only one user.

First you need a UserAspect model which has a user_id and a aspect_type and aspect_id

```
class UserAspect < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :aspect, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Now your user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  #aspects
  has_many :user_aspects
  has_many :aspects, :through => :user_aspects

end
```

And now your medic

```
class Medic < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :license_number, :specialty

  has_one :user_aspect, as: :aspect, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :user, :through => :user_aspect
end
```

Now you can do things like

```
user.aspects

medic.user

etc
```

Comment: First many thanks! But I do not understand why you use a model more, I'll show you my idea in simple tables maybe we can come to understand. **Simplifying models** **TABLE USERS** (id, username, password,usersable_type, usersable_id) **TABLE MEDICS** (id, license_number, specialty) **TABLE PACIENTS** (id, blood_type, birthday) and then I can use **user.usersable** where usersable can be a Medic or Patient. **I know it can be done but I dont know how** ** Thank a lot!!**

Comment: Hi, In your previous comment on the question you said that a doctor could have many patients, and a doctor is a user.  if the usersable_type, usersable_id in the user table, how can a single user have many patients?  Or is a Doctor another table?

Comment: Thank you so much for help me!!, Yes exists the table **Medic** and I have other table **medics_patients** because One Patient could have many Medics, and a Medic has many patients. **Thank you!!**

Comment: Edit the main post, the error still is the same, I dont know how create and save the polymorphic object.

Comment: Using my example and not using ours.  you would do the following: u = user.find(x), m = Medic.find(x)  Medic.user = u

Comment: Adding belong_to :user in the models Patient and Medic I could do the same, and I dont need other model, **thank you!!**, Sorry for insist but I want to understand and learn it. My problem is not being able to create and save the polymorphic object, you know how?

Comment: Sure but you will need to put the user_id in Patient and Medic and not use polymorphic association

Comment: Read this as it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557548/rails-polymorphic-user-model-with-devise . It has a user model with polymorphic and has 2 more table just like yours. The only difference is that he is able to get it to work without overriding RegistrationsController. Your goals are not the same, but it should give you fresh or alternative ideas that might lead to a solution.